# How to solve this error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reply_text'?

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, attributeerror, python-telegram-bot

I've a button , it's supposed to return the ask_wikipedia function , so I used CallbackQueryHandler but when i want to call ask_wikipedia function i recive an attribute error !
Why?
How can i fix it ?

```py
def Click_Button(update, context) :
    query = update.callback_query
    if query.data == "Research":
        ask_wikipedia(update, context)

query_handler = CallbackQueryHandler(Click_Button)

dispatcher.add_handler(query_handler)



def ask_wikipedia(update, context)  :
    update.message.reply_text('What do you want to know about ? ')
    return About
```

When I click on the button I get this error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reply_text'
```

How can I fix it ?

Comment: Do you have a return statement in the CallbackQueryHandler function?

Comment: no i don't think so ...

Comment: query_handler is going to be a NoneType then. You should add a return statement for whatever you want to be saved in the query_handler variable.

Comment: sorry I'm literally a noob , How can i add a return statement ?

Comment: No worries haha. "return About" is an example of a return statement in your "ask_wikipedia" function. So just add "return" followed by the variable you want as the output of the function as the last line of the function. Watch the indentation too. It should only be one level in from the edge.

Comment: do you mean , I should return the update "return update " , what am i going to return?

Comment: You don't have the CallbackQueryHandler function definition in your code so I can't say what you should return. But whatever you put after "return" in the CallbackQueryHandler function is what query_handler is going to have as a value.

Answer (score 5):

When replying to a text message (from a `MessageHandler`) is fine to use `update.message.reply_text`, but in your case the incoming message is a managed by the CallbackHandler which receives a different object.
You can reply using

```
update.callback_query.message.edit_text(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

Faced `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reply_text'` error in my app. After investigation found that it raises when user edit original message, so in update I get `edited_message` instead of `message`. So I decided to use `update.effective_chat.send_message` instead of `update.message.reply_text` to avoid this problem. Even if it not solution for you, keep in mind that it might be `edited_message` in update instead of `message`.
(Wrote here because it is first in google for this Error)