# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'chat_id' telegram bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I got `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'chat_id'` when i click the MESSAGE button .
I think the problem is context=update.message.chat_id (of context.job_queue.run_daily - method message).
Another problem is that I get the message when I click, not at 12:00 (the time i put in the method run_daily)

```
def start(update:Update, context:CallbackContext) -> int:
                
    options = [[InlineKeyboardButton("MESSAGE", callback_data="DAILY_MESSAGE")]]
                        
    optionsMenu = InlineKeyboardMarkup(options)
                        
    update.message.reply_text("Welcome", reply_markup=optionsMenu)
                        
    return FIRST
    
    
def messageText(update, context):
    context.bot.send_message(
            chat_id=update.callback_query.from_user.id, 
            text="Message received",
            parse_mode=ParseMode.MARKDOWN
            )
            
def message(update, context):
    context.job_queue.run_daily(messageText(update, context),
                                time=time(hour=12, minute=0, second=0, tzinfo=pytz.timezone("Europe/Madrid")),
                                days=(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6),
                                context=update.message.chat_id)
    
    
def main():
    updater = Updater("API_KEY", use_context=True)
    dp = updater.dispatcher
    
    
    conv_handler = ConversationHandler(
        entry_points=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
        states={
            FIRST: [
                CallbackQueryHandler(message, pattern='^DAILY_MESSAGE$')
            ],
        },
        fallbacks=[CommandHandler('start', start)],
    )
    
    dp.add_handler(conv_handler)
        
    updater.start_polling()
    updater.idle()
```

Any solution? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve this error : AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reply\_text'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66564632/how-to-solve-this-error-attributeerror-nonetype-object-has-no-attribute-re)

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the `AttributeError`, please see the question that I linked in the comments. Regarding `I get the message when I click, not at 12:00`:

`job_queue.run_*` need to know which function to run at the specified time. In your case, it should run `messageText`. But instead of passing that function, you pass `messageText(update, context)`. This means that you already call `messageText` by passing the parameters and then pass the return value of that call to `job_queue.run_daily`. Also note that `messageText` must take only one positional argument, which is `context`, as jobs are not triggered by updates.

Please read the [tutorial on `JobQueue`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Extensions-%E2%80%93-Job-Queue) in the PTB wiki.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`.

Comment: I have changed the method and it works, but only if I create a CommandHandler with it, but I don't want that. I want the method to work when I click the button.